# How to make a part of an svg image act as a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, svg

I currently have an SVG image looking like
**this**
[image: this]

the code for that is:

```
    <svg width="360" height="65" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M180 55c16.569 0 30-13.431 30-30 0-2.77-.376-5.453-1.078-8H360v48H0V17h151.078A30.068 30.068 0 00150 25c0 16.569 13.431 30 30 30z" fill="#3D3B8E"/>
      <g filter="url(#addBook__filter0_di)">
        <path d="M205 25c0 13.807-11.193 25-25 25s-25-11.193-25-25 11.193-25 25-25 25 11.193 25 25z" fill="#E072A4"/>
      </g>
      <path d="M187 26h-6v6h-2v-6h-6v-2h6v-6h2v6h6v2z" fill="#F9F9F9"/>
      <defs>
        <filter id="addBook__filter0_di" x="151" y="0" width="58" height="60" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="4"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
          <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
          <feBlend in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
          <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
          <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
          <feOffset dy="10"/>
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10"/>
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1"/>
          <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.878431 0 0 0 0 0.447059 0 0 0 0 0.643137 0 0 0 0.5 0"/>
          <feBlend in2="shape" result="effect2_innerShadow"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

I used [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)  package to add the SVG file and then used `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to make it responsive, then wrapped the whole thing inside the `Align()` and moved it to the bottom center of the screen. Now I want to know how to make the `GestureDetector()` to only sense the button and not the whole thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While arguably there are better ways to make that UI layout and have onTap functionality for the mid round button, GestureDetector's onTap provides the position of the tap. Given that you know the width of the on-screen image you can figure out if the tap happened on the area that you are interested in. With that said I suggest that you try building this UI in a different way. Right now there is no tap visual feedback and you run into weird cases like the one you are trying to solve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you can handle the `responsive`. Since it is a Single widget and I don't know is there any way to extract elements from SVG I'm using stack to handle this situation.

**Only Green is area tappable**

[image: output]

```
 SizedBox(
                  height: 65,
                  width: 360,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        "so.svg",
                        height: 65,
                        width: 360,
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          print("clicked");
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 65 * .8,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            // color: Colors.green.withOpacity(.4),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

please try with this

```
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print("clicked");
                  },
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    "assets/images/image.svg",
                    width: width,
                  ),
                )),
          ],
        )
```

Output:
[image]